# Mongoose hook "pre/post save" not working for findOneAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using nodejs + express + mongoose.

I add "pre/post save" hook for a module, it works fine with save function.
But when I use findOneAndUpdate (create if it not exist), the hook is not called.

It seemed the only way I can do is separate findOneAndUpdate to two function, search item first then do create.

Is there a better idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From mongoose documentation:

> Although values are cast to their appropriate types when using the findAndModify helpers, the following are not applied:
>
> - defaults
> - setters
> - validators
> - middleware
>
> If you need those features, use the traditional approach of first retrieving the document.

[reference](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)

**UPDATE:** Since Mongoose 4.0 you could use `runValidators` option, from Changelog:

> [#860](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/860): You can optionally run validators and set defaults if a new document is created on update() and findOneAndUpdate() calls. In order to access these features, you must explicitly set the runValidators and setDefaultsOnInsert options when you call update() or findOneAndUpdate(). Note that the setDefaultsOnInsert option is not compatible with MongoDB <= 2.2. Further note update() and findOneAndUpdate() explicitly run validators with a null context (that is, this === null in the validator function).

Comment: { runValidators: true } is available as third parameter in mongoose 4

Answer (score 0):

I opted for another approach. Basically all my logic is in the **Pre-save** middleware. Then when I want to update the values on the **findOneAndUpdate** middleware I am saving the document. That triggers again the logic. May be helpful to somebody.

Comment: True but when you are saving it, that triggers the pre-save middleware.